# How do I display items in a RecyclerView one by one onButtonClick instead of loading all questions at once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of questions with answer choices(let us assume 5 questions). Currently, all 5 questions are loaded at once in the RecyclerView, so a student can answer all the questions in the view. I would like to change this such that the first question loads and only after the student has answered and clicks the submit button, will the second load and so on. In other words, submit the answer to question 1, the view clears and shows question 2 and so on. An example of an app that I have seen achieve that is Duolingo. You only see the next question after you have submitted the current one displayed. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Add more code so as to solve your question using your own variables and logic

Comment: @Xenolion I do not have the logic yet, as I am unsure how to go about this all together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to show only one question at a time, you don't need to use a `RecyclerView` at all. Just use text views and reuse them.

If you want to display old questions when a new question is unlocked, you may handle it in the `getItemCount()` method of your RecyclerView's adapter.

First sort the questions in order and use:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return currentQuestionIndex + 1;
}
```

After that, when the next button is clicked, increment the current question's index and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `RecyclerView`.

If you want to display only one question and use `RecyclerView` anyway, return 1 from the `getItemCount` method. Then in the `onBindViewHolder` method instead of using the `position` parameter to get item from the list, use `list.get(currentQuestionIndex);`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Question question = questionList.get(currentQuestionIndex);
    //other code
}
```

Comment: If don't want to display old question, just clear the dataset, and add the next question and call `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: I tried to use textviews and reuse them but it was quite difficult to think through it and I settled for the RecyclerView. The questions are sorted by level though and shuffled.

Comment: @NabinBhandari where do you declare `currentQuestionIndex`?

Comment: Anywhere you like. It may be declared as a field in your adapter.

Comment: @NabinBhandari I have the questions showing one at a time now. So, i have added the button that will control the changing questions. How do I select the next question in the sequence to display onbuttonclick or do I just remove the question that I have already displayed

Comment: @NabinBhandari sorry I missed that section.